# How can you have a Vim-like-Taglist in Emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs, taglist

I use AquaEmacs.

I would like to have Emacs which has a vertical hierarchy (at the left-hand-side) about items in the document, similar to Vim's plugin Taglist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`M-x speedbar`.

http://cedet.sourceforge.net/speedbar.shtml

Comment: Thank you!

For AquaEmacs users, you can find by Speedbar by typing it to help (C-h). AquaEmacs has it by default.

Answer (score 3):

There's a fresh blog post I'd consider quite useful regarding this topic.

http://frankpzh.wordpress.com/category/emacs/

Very light weight and works without pain. So far it doesn't seem to work with anything else than C and C++ but that could be a mistake of my own.

cu
Roman

Comment: Works well with Ruby and JS for me.